# How do sorting extbase repository Objects by mm.sorting

Tags: sorting, repository, typo3, extbase

I have a TYPO3 Extension with two Model, `Member` and `Category` and M:M relation between this models.
Now I write a special repository method `findByCategoryUid` to get members sorted by Date.

How can I sort/order the Member Objects by the field `tx_***member_membercategory_mm.sorting` ?

This one dosn't work.

```
$query->setOrderings(
    array('tx_***_member_membercategory_mm.sorting' => \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Persistence\QueryInterface::ORDER_ASCENDING)
);
```

Answer (score 1):

When working with the Extbase repositories/queries you should forget about the mysql tables and just look at your models. To sort by a related field you have to use your model fields. If your categories are in the field `category` in the `Member` model, than you need to use `category.sorting` as the sorting field. The same goes for filtering in the query.

```
$query->setOrderings(
    array('category.sorting' => \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Persistence\QueryInterface::ORDER_ASCENDING)
);
```

It only works if you configured the TCA and your models right.

Comment: thats the wrong way. I will port my plain SQL query to using repository methods.
My query looks like `Select Member.* FROM Member, Member_Cat_MM, Category WHERE Member.uid = Member_Categoy_MM.uid_local and Category.uid = Member_Category_MM.uid_foreign = Category.uid GROUP BY Member.uid ORDER BY Member_Category_MM.sorting ASC`